# Sort array of Objects while iteration - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object that I'm iterating and pushing to a new array.
I also want that the new array will be sorted by a specific value (without using .sort())
Array

```
arr1 = [
   {name: "three", value: 16}
   {name: "one", value: 2}
   {name: "two", value: 12}
]
```

Wanted result

```
arr2 = [
   {name: "one", value: 2},
   {name: "two", value: 12},
   {name" "three", value: 16}
]
```

tried

```
arr1.forEach(item => {
if (arr2.length) {
   const lastObj = arr2[arr2.length - 1];
   if (item.value > lastObj.value) {
     arr2.push(item)
   } else {
    arr2.unshift(item)
   }
} else {
 arr2.push(item)
}
})
```

Comment: I would look at sorting algorithms since you only ever look at the first index, not going to work.

Comment: Try to clone this array and write a comparator for the new array so this is left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing to a single value won't work, because the next value could be between the previous elements. Sorting is a very complicated matter and extensively studied by computer science. If you don't want to touch your original array, just clone it before sorting:

```js
arr1 = [
   {name: "three", value: 16},
   {name: "one", value: 2},
   {name: "two", value: 12}
]

arr2 = [...arr1].sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the array based on the value

```js
const arr1 = [
   {name: "three", value: 16},
   {name: "one", value: 2},
   {name: "two", value: 12},
];

const output = arr1.sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

merge is a good way to sort without using sort()

```js
arr1 = [
   {name: "three", value: 16},
   {name: "one", value: 2},
   {name: "two", value: 12}
]
console.log(mergeSort(arr1))
function mergeSort(arr)
{
    if (arr.length < 2)
        return arr;

    var middle = parseInt(arr.length / 2);
    var left   = arr.slice(0, middle);
    var right  = arr.slice(middle, arr.length);

    return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
}

function merge(left, right)
{
    var result = [];

    while (left.length && right.length) {
        if (left[0].value <= right[0].value) {
            result.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            result.push(right.shift());
        }
    }

    while (left.length)
        result.push(left.shift());

    while (right.length)
        result.push(right.shift());

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't compare actual value to not defined in sort array value.
its crashing everything, your idea.